# How can I configure two mails for two different users in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, ssmtp

I am struggling with configuring `two mails for two different users` in Ubuntu.
Like if I login with `User1` then whenever I use the command mail, it should send mail from `user1@gmail.com`.

And when User2 logins with its credentials then it should send mail from `user2@gmail.com`.

Currently I've changed my `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` for my Gmail id.
But when I send mail from a different user, the same mail id is been used.

Can anyone please provide any pointer or links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the `mail` command (aka `mailx`) you should be able to add this to the `~/.mailrc` file for each user:

```
set from="user1@gmail.com"
```

`mutt` follows the same syntax except `~/.muttrc` is the file you edit.

Comment: :Thank this worked for me ,you made my day cheers

Comment: mailrc is read by ssmtp?